# Django DateTimeField was messy with naive and aware timestamp field in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone

Version:

Django 1.11

PostgreSQL 9.6 (AWS RDS)

Django settings.py:

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_TZ = False

My Problem:

In last year, My django app migrated database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. It was fine. But I found big trouble.

Tables that was generated in MySQL have DateTimeField, which correspond to naive timestamp field (without timezone) in PostgreSQL. But tables that was generated in PostgreSQL have DateTimeField, which correspond to aware timestamp field (with timezone). It stores all timestamp in UTC.

So My DB tables was messy with naive and aware timestamp field.

How do I fix this issue at best?

The Followings are solutions I think,

1. Convert naive timestamp fields to aware timestamp fields.
   I think It's best practice. But naive timestamp fields are too many. and I'm afraid that I lost data due to converting.
2. Convert aware timestamp fields to naive timestamp fields.
   I think It's one of easy ways. But I heard naive timestamp fields are not practice.
3. Nothing changed. Actually, I didn't know timestamp field is messy until I examine DB. Djano application has worked well now. But I worry It's big trouble in the future.
4. Change timezone setting in AWS RDS. Is it possible and solution?

Sorry for my poor english. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Convert naive timestamp fields to aware timestamp fields. I think It's best practice. But naive timestamp fields are too many. and I'm afraid that I lost data due to converting.

You're correct, the best result will be to get all the naive values to timezone-aware values. Perhaps you want to ask a new question about the problem that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decide to convert all timestamp field from naive to aware.